# Java makefile under windows chokes on accent marks

Tags: java, makefile

First off, I'm sorry if this is trivial, I have no experience with make files, I only develop on Windows and I'm used to IDEs.

I need to compile an external java library. It comes with a makefile. Unfortunately I'm having a lot of trouble getting it to run.

I installed make and grep from the GnuWin32 toolset and added it to my path variable.
When I try to run the makefile it chokes on:

```
"javac: invalid flag: `find"
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

It seems like it has problems interpreting the accent mark. Is that supposed to be a quotation mark killed by text encoding? I did a quick google search but I'm not finding anything relevant.

Here is the full make file I'm trying to get to run:

```
# UNIX:
#JAVAC=javac -encoding utf8 -target 1.6 -source 1.6 -Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked -cp "../lib/asm-4.1.jar:../lib/asm-analysis-4.1.jar:../lib/asm-commons-4.1.jar:../lib/asm-tree-4.1.jar:../lib/asm-util-4.1.jar:../lib/asm-xml-4.1.jar:../lib/junit-4.0.jar"
# Win32:
JAVAC=javac -encoding utf8 -target 1.6 -source 1.6 -Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked -cp "../lib/asm-4.1.jar;../lib/asm-analysis-4.1.jar;../lib/asm-commons-4.1.jar;../lib/asm-tree-4.1.jar;../lib/asm-util-4.1.jar;../lib/asm-xml-4.1.jar;../lib/junit-4.0.jar"
JAVA=java
SOURCES=`find . -name "*.java" | grep -v \\\#`
JAR=pqlib.jar

.PHONY = all default clean test benchmark jar

default: all

all:
    ${JAVAC} `find . -name "*.java" | grep -v \\\#` 

clean:
    rm -f `find . -name "*.class"`

test: all
    ${JAVA} org.junit.runner.JUnitCore `find edu -name "*Test.java" | grep -v \\\# | sed 's/^\.\///' | sed 's/\.java//' | tr '/' '.'`

benchmark: all bench/MiniBench.class
    ${JAVA} bench.MiniBench

jar: all
    rm -f ${JAR}
    jar cf ${JAR} `find edu -name "*.class" | grep -v Test`
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [tag:cygwin] provides `find` and _backtick_ command substitution on `Windows`.

Comment: It should be possible to enter the directory tree of this library into Eclipse (or some other IDE) and compile it there, and build the jar. The make file doesn't do anything remarkable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to install Cygwin32 and add its bin directory to your path.

The commands `find`, `grep` etc. are all part of it. OR you can install them one by one as you did with `grep`.

Is there an README or INSTALL file that comes with your library? This things are usually explained in those files.

Comment: Sadly the readme file has zero information on installation and just covers where to find some important classes.

I added find too GnuWin too, but it still feeds `find to javac as a parameter instead of resolving it first (I guess).

I'm downloading cygwin now, though the installer alone is already giving me a headache. Sticking to the base and devel packages, hopefully that's enough.